# Is clearing a vector of a class containg vector enough to clear everything?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

Let's consider a class that contains a vector:

```
AGivenClass
{

public:

 vector< int > vec_int;

};
```

and let's consider that we have an instance, which is a vector of the class :

```
vector < AGivenClass > vec_instance;
```

My question is :
Is doing

```
vec_instance.clear()
```

*enough* to free memory, including for the previously filled vec_int internal to the class ?

Comment: Yes, it's enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : thank you so much. You may put your nice comment to the answer so that I could validate it. Thanks

Comment: No, it's not enough. You also need to call `shrink_to_fit`

Comment: @user7860670  : sorry : could you comment a bit further ?

Comment: and what about if I would have in the class a vector of *pointer* ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Please beware that there is a difference between the question "What do I need to call so that all memory is released?" and "What do I need to call so that there won't be a memory leak?". As long as you don't use raw `new` or similar stuff and with few exceptions (such as circular `std::shared_ptr` or C-style APIs) you never need to release memory manually in C++ to avoid memory leaks, but you need to if you want to free memory prematurely before objects leave their scope and are destroyed automatically.

Comment: @user7860670 your claim is wrong and misleading. When `vector` of `AGivenClass` is cleaned all instances of `AGivenClass` inside it are destroyed and as a result all memory of `vector< int >` is released. Probably you are thinking about memory associated with `std::vector<AGivenClass>`, but this was not a questioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec_instance.clear()` will destoy all the contained objects, but won't deallocate memory buffer used to store them. Vector capacity won't change. So you also need to call `vec_instance.shrink_to_fit()` to make sure that all the memory is deallocated. Vector capacity should become 0 afterwards.

Comment: ok thank you. Bonus : and what if my class includes a vector of pointer : should I first delete the pointers before to clear my vector of instance ?

Comment: But it is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(), according to docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Bonus question:for raw pointers: that depends if you're really done with the objects the pointers point to or not.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian it should be a vector of *smart* pointers so there will be a proper RAII style cleanup performed without you writing any additional code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  : yes I mean that I no more needs the pointer at this stage. *Should* I delete them, or is the vector::clear() enough ? I use *standard* pointers.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian every raw pointer you've got via `new` must be deleted via `delete`, so yes, in that case you need to delete them beforehand

Comment: @ks1322 In practice this request is always fulfilled, especially when the size is 0.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian [You should not use naked `new`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). Always use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` instead and you won't ever need to think about memory leaks.